# How make this @font-face work in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, templates, font-face

How to make @font-face work in my Wordpress template ?

this is the css code

```
 @font-face {
 font-family: 'BorisBlackBloxx';
src: url ('http://www.make-sport.ru/wp-content/themes/make-sport/fonts/borisblackbloxx-webfont.eot');
src: url ('http://www.make-sport.ru/wp-content/themes/make-sport/fonts/borisblackbloxx-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url ('http://www.make-sport.ru/wp-content/themes/make-sport/fonts/borisblackbloxx-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url ('http://www.make-sport.ru/wp-content/themes/make-sport/fonts/BorisBlackBloxx.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url ('http://www.make-sport.ru/wp-content/themes/make-sport/fonts/borisblackbloxx-webfont.svg#BorisBlackBloxxRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

```
.logo a{
font-family: 'BorisBlackBloxx', helvetica, arial;
font-size: 72px;
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
```

}

this is HTML markup

```
   <div class="grid_12">

      <h1 class="logo">
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">MAKE SPORT</a>
      </h1>

    </div> <!-- logo end -->
```

I read all the posts on this site and not one of them was not help me.

T tryed make different things with the paths and take the @font-face code from css to the html in the   tag, nothing works

How do you think, that's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the targeting is correct, but the font isn't read properly. Try placing the font embedding code in your main style sheet (style.css). Preferable near the top of the document.

Comment: Most strange that font-face work great at the local wordpress,
 but the same theme and the same code didn't work at the same wordpress version but at the hosting

Answer (score 0):

I just looked through the source of your site.

The only place I could find that you were trying to use the 'BorisBlackBloxx'  font was on `.logo a`, however the text in there is in an image.

It should go without saying that font files can not change the font used in images. Are you using this somewhere else on the page that I am not seeing.

Also, if thats the case, have you tried a variety of browsers?